# Probability of Intersecting Intervals

Tags: probability

Given a set of intervals $S=\{s_1,s_2,\dots,s_m\}$. All the intervals have the same length and all randomly placed within $[0,1]$. That is the start point of each interval is randomly selected within $[0,1]$. 
I am interested in what follows:

1-  considering the $s_1$ interval, what the probability that all other intervals $S \setminus \{s_1\}$ are not overlapped with $s_1$?

2-  what is the probability that at least two intervals are overlapped with $s_1$?

Comment: If the length of each interval is $d$ and the start point is randomly placed with uniform distribution in $[0,1],$ then with probability $d$ the start point is in $(1-d,1]$ and the end point is in $(1,1+d]$, so the interval is not contained in $[0,1]$.